# Can't install Office on windows

Tags: windows-7, installation, microsoft-office-2007

I have reinstalled Windows 7 and now trying to install Microsoft Office 2007,but it gives strange error

```
Setup can't find "Office.en-us\DW20-EXE"
```

Please give me some hints on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please, next time, add more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three options you can try ([found here](http://www.brilliantthinking.net/2009/03/13/setup-cannot-find-officeen-usdwtrig20exe/)):

> 1) Are you using Skype? If you are, remove it completely, install
>   Office and then install Skype again. This usually fixes the problem.
>
> 2A) Open the parent folder manually that the installer cannot find.
>   When you get the error, use Windows Explorer to find the parent folder
>   of the folder that contains the missing file. Run the Office install
>   again. Repeat this step if you get any more files not found. Leave
>   them open in separate Windows Explorer windows until Office is
>   installed.
>
> 2B) Open the files manually that the installer cannot find. When you
>   get the error, use Windows Explorer to find the file and open it
>   manually. Leave it open and run the Office install again. Repeat this
>   step if you get any more files not found. Leave them open until Office
>   is installed.
>
> 3) Edit the registry. This is the last option and care should be
>   taken not to break your machine. I take no responsibility for any
>   changes you make to your computer (either in this step or the previous
>   ones). To edit the registry click on START, then RUN ... In the box
>   that appears type REGEDIT and click OK. Browse down the following
>   path:
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > MICROSOFT > OFFICE`
>
> Delete the keys (items) you find in the OFFICE folder but not the
>   sub-folders. This removes traces of previous installs to avoid
>   possible conflicts when installing the new version of Office.
>
> Then browse into:
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > MICROSOFT > OFFICE > DELIVERY >
>   SOURCEENGINE > DOWNLOADS`
>
> Delete the keys (items) you find here.