# Error during installation of assembly components in Office 2007

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2007

After [yesterday's question](https://superuser.com/q/356499/48078) I've tried to install Office 2007.

I have replaced many components and at the beginning, the installation process was running fine. In the middle part however it outputs the following error:

> Error 1935:An error occured during the installation of assembly components
>   {97F81Af1-0E47-DC99-A01F-c8B3B9A1E18E},Hresult:0x80070BC9

What is cause of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Repair the Microsoft .NET Framework version 2.0 installation**

To repair the Microsoft .NET Framework version 2.0 installation, follow these steps:
Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Add or Remove Programs.
In the Currently installed programs list, click Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0, and then click Change/Remove.
Click Repair, and then click Next.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue installing on a clean installation of 64-bit Windows 7. I went to Control Panel → Programs and Features → Turn Windows features on or off, cleared the checkbox for .NET and restarted. After that the installation of Office worked. Finally I turned the features back on and updated Windows.